# How to switch off the message tone in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I want to switch off the message tone in Facebook. That is the beep sound that chimes when any of my friends messages me via chat. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Help Centre](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14424):

> How do I turn off/on sound when I get an IM (instant message) in Facebook Chat?
>
> To disable or enable the notification sound, please follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Select the "Chat" menu button in the lower right corner of any Facebook page.
> 2. Click the "Settings" link.
> 3. Check the box next to "Play Sound for New Messages."
>
> If the sound setting has not changed when you receive chat messages, please log out of your account and sign back in.

Comment: Thank you. Most annoying feature in the history of the Internet and not intuitive that it would be under chat even when chat is turned off.